# Prevent translation animation from keeping the original position of view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

Using the translation animation with a value of say 50f on the x axis will move the object 50 pixels to the right:

```
val animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(draggableImage1, "translationX", 50f)
```

But after that translation, the animation still "remembers" the original position of the object, so calling the exact same method again won't move the object at all, because it's already set 50 pixels to the right. Is this way to prevent this behavior? Meaning, after the animation was complete, the new position of the object will be set as the original position, and if we call an animation translation again, it will be re-calculated from the new position?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code doesn't respect current view position. Change it to draggableImage1.getX + 50f, and it'll be work.

Comment: You're right that the increments of each animation will be the same, but it's tough to say, increment by a fixed number that you want to determine such as 20px every time. I know it's possible but I was wondering if it's possible to set the animator to calculate from the current position and not the original.
I guess there isn't such option, thanks anyway

Comment: @sir-haver, oh, sorry, I didn't quite understand correctly your question.